# Got the “Dead kernel” message from Jupyter Notebook on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My PC crashed while I was running something on Jupyter Notebook, after that I always get the message **"Dead kernel"** when I try to use Jupyter Notebook, I even uninstalled and reinstalled and the problem persists.

This is the message I get:

[image]

This is where the problem starts, from the CMD:

[image]

**What can I do? Please help... I need to do a homework with Jupyter Notebook...**

The version I'm using is: Anaconda3-4.0.0-Windows-x86_64

Comment: Run `ipython locate profile` in the command prompt to see where the profile folder is. In that folder you'll find a `history.sqlite` file. Rename or remove that. If that doesn't fix it, try to find the end of the error message and post that.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!! I was going to give up on that homework